# How do I remove uninstalled program in 'open with > choose another app' menu?

Tags: windows, format, winamp

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8zXz.png), I've checked the registry but no idea which one I should remove. Should I do it for each file extension?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do it:

1. Via Regedit
2. Via 3rd party software

Be aware that with option 1 you need to be very careful what you modifying or removing.

If you are not feeling comfortable with messing around in you regedit (which I totally understand), I would recommend starting with the 3rd party option first.

The following link explains the exact steps to take: [https://www.maketecheasier.com/remove-apps-from-windows-open-with-list/#:~:text=To%20remove%20a%20program%20from,of%20%E2%80%9Copen%20with%E2%80%9D%20programs](https://www.maketecheasier.com/remove-apps-from-windows-open-with-list/#:%7E:text=To%20remove%20a%20program%20from,of%20%E2%80%9Copen%20with%E2%80%9D%20programs).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).